# Salting ground Turkey

Tags: salt

I am vegetarian but cook meat for my husband. As such, I don’t know much about seasoning meat. I know salting foods is a matter of taste, but if I am sautéing 1 pound ground turkey with onions and herbs would a tablespoon of salt be in the ball park of what I would need to use? I am talking about table salt, not kosher salt. Would one use less salt on ground products vs whole meat because it would penetrate the meat so much easier with ground?

Is there a rough guideline one can provide such as for xx pounds of xx meat suggest xx amount of salt?

Comment: A tablespoon is far, far, far too much. As asked this can't be answered because it's partly personal taste: how salty does your husband like his food?

Answer (score 1):

For raw meats, poultry, fish, and seafood: 3/4 to 1 teaspoon Kosher salt per pound (and even that varies, depending on the type and the size of salt flakes). If using table salt, cut back to 1/2 to 3/4 teaspoons per pound or even less.
I would start with the lower amount, and see if your husband thinks finished dishes needs a bit more. Then you can adjust up or down over time.

Answer (score 0):

I would only suggest no more than a teaspoon.  Table salt has much more sodium than kosher by almost 2X.  In addition, if you are using store bought ground turkey, there is a good chance it may have also been processed with sodium.  Best to stay low.

Comment: A teaspoon sounds too much. You haven’t really said what you’re making, but I’d just be adding a “healthy pinch” as you cook it and then adjust it at the end by tasting. In your case “tasting” will mean dragging your husband into the kitchen (if he is reluctant then he just gets whatever comes!)

Comment: Table salt has about the same amount of sodium as kosher salt.  One difference is that the size of table salt crystals are smaller than kosher, so more of them fit into a given measure (tsp, for example). So if you measure a tsp of each, you are actually using more salt if you are measuring table salt.